# Shorten SQL Syntax of LIKE Clause to IN Clause

Tags: sql

In SQL,
Is there any way to Shorten syntax From

```
Select * from TableName
where ColumnName like '%A%' or ColumnName like '%B' or ColumnName like 'C%'
```

To

```
Select * from TableName
where ColumnName in ('%A%','%B','C%')
```

It is not feasible to write same column name in `Where` clause with `OR` again and again.

Comment: use Full Text Searching. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: I think you need to reconduct your feasability study. The SQL Server engine said it wasn't feasible to iterate over all those char but then ... (see my previous comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a way to combine LIKE with IN *directly*

There are ways around this, like this example for SQL Server

```
Select *
from
   TableName T
   JOIN
   (VALUES ('%A%'),('%B'),('C%')) AS X(Expression) ON T.ColumnName LIKE X.Expression
```

This changes multiple OR search conditions into rows and a JOIN

Or you can use a UNION to combine several queries in one

```
Select * from TableName
where ColumnName like '%A%'
union
Select * from TableName
where ColumnName like '%B'
union
Select * from TableName
where ColumnName like 'C%'
```