# How to select with N like

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a problem with my project when work with MSSQL

TableName: **tbA**

```
ID | COL
---+------
1  | 'abc'
2  | 'azc'
3  | 'xyz'
4  | '123'
```

Proceduce: **pSearch(@input string)**

I want to select tbA combines LIKE, IN and OR with ideal:

`SELECT * FROM tbA a WHERE a.Z IN ('"a%c" OR "x%"')`

Something like it, and maybe I have a solution that's full-text search but I don't want to use it.

And my expectation

```
ID | COL
---+------
1  | 'abc'
2  | 'azc'
3  | 'xyz'
```

I hope people give me a solution or something else, thanks all.

Comment: Similar Question Here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459144/shorten-sql-syntax-of-like-clause-to-in-clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459144/shorten-sql-syntax-of-like-clause-to-in-clause)

Answer (score 4):

Variant 1.

```
SELECT * FROM tbA a WHERE a.Z LIKE 'a%c' OR a.Z LIKE 'x%'
```

Variant 2.

```
DECLARE @tPattern_ TABLE (pat VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @tPattern_ (pat)
SELECT 'a%c' UNION ALL SELECT 'x%'

SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM tbA a
INNER JOIN @tPattern_ p ON a.Z LIKE p.pat
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant 3.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (title NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp (title)
VALUES ('a c'), ('x1111'), ('blank')

SELECT t.*
FROM @temp t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES ('a%c'), ('x%')) c(t)  
    WHERE title LIKE t
)
```